# MATLAB: Not Enough Input Arguements

Tags: matlab

I've attempted to run this code multiple times and have had zero luck since I added in the last for loop. Before the error, the vector k wouldn't update so the vector L was the same number repeated.

I can't figure out why I am getting the 'Not enough input arguments' error when it was working fine beforehand.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
% Set up parameters of the functions
omega = 2*pi/10; % 1/s    
g = 9.81; % m/s^2
h = 20; % m
parms = [omega, g, h];
% Set up the root finding variables
etol = 1e-6; % convergence criteria
iter = 100; % maximum number of iterations
f = @my_fun; % function pointer to my_func
fp = @my_fprime; % function pointer to my_fprime
k0 = kguess(parms); % initial guess for root
% Find the root
[k, error, n_iterations] = newtraph(f, fp, k0, etol, iter, parms);
% Get the wavelength
if n_iterations < iter
% Converged correctly
L = 2 * pi / k;
else
% Did not converge
disp('ERROR: Maximum number of iterations exceeded')
return
end

wave = load('wavedata.dat');
dt = 0.04; %s
%dh = 0.234; %water depth in meters
wave = wave*.01; %covnverts from meters to cm
nw = wave([926:25501],1);
a = length(nw);
t = 0;
spot = 1;
points  = zeros(1,100);
for i = 1:a-1
    t=t+dt;
    if nw(i) < 0 
        if nw(i+1) > 0
        points(spot)=t;
        spot=spot+1;
        t=0;
        end
    end
end

omega = 2*pi./points; %w
l = length(points);
L = zeros(1,509);
k = zeros(1,509);
for j = 1:l
g = 9.81; % m/s^2
h = 0.234; % m
parms = [omega(j), g, h];
% Set up the root finding variables
etol = 1e-6; % convergence criteria
iter = 100; % maximum number of iterations
f = @my_fun; % function pointer to my_func
fp = @my_fprime; % function pointer to my_fprime
k0(j) = kguess(parms); % initial guess for root
% Find the root
[k(j), error, n_iterations] = newtraph(f, fp, k0(j), etol, iter, parms);
% Get the wavelength
if n_iterations < iter
    % Converged correctly
    L(j) = 2 * pi / k(j);
else
    % Did not converge
    disp('ERROR: Maximum number of iterations exceeded')
    return
end
end

    function [ f ] = my_fun(k,parms)
%MY_FUN creates a function handle for linear dispersion
%   Detailed explanation goes here
w = parms(1) ;
g = parms(2);
h = parms(3);

f = g*k*tanh(k*h)-(w^2);
end

    function [ fp ] = my_fprime(k,parms)
%MY_FPRIME creates a function handle for first derivative of linear 
%   dispersion.

g = parms(2);
h = parms(3);
% w = 2*pi/10; % 1/s
% g = 9.81; % m/s^2
% h = 20; % m

fp = g*(k*h*((sech(k*h)).^2) + tanh(k*h));

end

    function [ k, error, n_iterations ] = newtraph( f, fp, k0, etol, iterA, parms )
%NEWTRAPH Estimates the value of k using the newton raphson method.
if nargin<3,error('at least 3 input arguments required'),end
if nargin<4|isempty(etol),es=etol;end
if nargin<5|isempty(iterA),maxit=iterA;end
iter = 0;
k = k0;
%func =@f;
%dfunc =@fp;
while (1)
    xrold = k;
    k = k - f(k)/fp(k);
    iter = iter + 1;
    if k ~= 0, ea = abs((k - xrold)/k) * 100; end
    if ea <= etol | iter >= iterA, break, end
end
error = ea;
n_iterations = iter;

end
```

Comment: In which line are you getting the error? Also.... You can not declare functions in a script.

Comment: [Functions in scripts](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions-in-scripts.html) has been added to 2016b so is now possible if he is on latest version.

Is the error not more verbose? Agree line number would be hopeful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function `newtraph` at line 106 (second line in the `while(1)` loop), you forgot to pass `parms` to the function call `f`:

```
k = k - f(k)/fp(k);
```

should become

```
k = k - f(k,parms)/fp(k,parms);
```

Comment: This was it. Thank you for the help!